# 10 liter fermentation crock... water getting sucked inside, advice needed

Tags: sauerkraut

Please assist regarding water added to the moat during a 4 to 5 week ferment, because one cannot simply keep adding water to the moat because if the  crock's vacuum is sucking in the water and you keep adding it will eventually reduce the salinity of the brine water and ruin your kraut!

My 1st batch I followed what i presumed were correct instructions and added water to the moat to keep full. Within 1 week I added 4 cups of water and discovered after lifting the lid for inspection the water was actually being sucked into the crock from the moat as the water level inside was clear up to the top of the crock! Initially I had at least 5 inches from the weight stones up to the top. The pulling of water into the crock fix no one has been able to tell me.

I thought well if it keeps pulling the water in from the moat that is not salted maybe it would be better to add salted water into the moat. Wrong! Because then it grew white mold or yeast floating all over the exposed moat salt water to the air & then since it was a real sucker and always thirsty that same white stuff got sucked into the crock and grew above the weights! So I skimmed off the white floaties best as possible, emptied the moat well and wiped clean & then refilled with clear distilled water & replaced the lid.

I have 2 more weeks to go before it is done and hope all my hard work and efforts & expense is not wasted. None of these issues is presented clearly or what to do to correct and I have searched tons online. I even emailed the store that sold me my 10 liter crock and they had no answers other than to just say "fermenting is an art that you just have to learn"! Wow, they were zero help after the sale.

Now the pros who know these answers and have faced such issues good luck trying to phone them or get the answers we all need because like an internet search you just do not get to THE person with THE knowledge needed after so much frustrations. The crock I bought the inner lip on the crock is the same height as the outer and this may be in part why water was getting sucked inside easier than those whose inner lip is higher? I did not know these things pre-purchase cuz nobody tells you.

I mainly bought my 100 + dollar 10 liter crock due to the convenient handles and the glass weights which are easier to clean & do not get moldy. Here is the one I bought: https://www.stonecreektrading.com/collections/fermenting-crocks-2/products/copy-of-fermenting-crock-10-liter-Egyptian-style-with-stone-weights  If anyone can help this issue of water being sucked into the crock and how to remedy please do so, then my next batch will be less of an issue hopefully.

Comment: The fermentation process creates CO2 with enough pressure to burst glass jars in come cases if not vented. Extreme temperature fluctuations might cause some retraction of the water in the outside channel, but that would tend to reverse upon a return to the previous temperature. Atmospheric pressure changes CAN cause dramatic changes in the level on the outside or inside, but would tend to be self limiting since if so much water were drawn to the inside of the channel, then it would lose its seal and equilibrate the presure - causing the water levels to return to normal.

Answer (score 5):

Is the crock kept in a place where the temperature is steady (such as a cellar/basement) or is it exposed to daily temperature swings? As a a rule the ferment should produce gas to some extent (which would push water out, if anything) but repeated temperature swings would tend to "pump" out when warm, in when colder. When the initial gas production slacks off, that could lead to water pumping in, particularly with a defectively non-tradtional design as you describe (I have looked at fermentation crocks a lot, and so far refused to spend money on them - but I soon grasped that the entire contents of the "moat" should not be able to rise above the inner lip in a "suck" situation, for precisely the reason you have experienced.)

One option would be to go back to a very basic airlock - a sheet of plastic wrap, or a (food grade) plastic bag, that covers the top of the crock, and a large rubber band holding it in place.

Another would be to NOT **fill** the moat - put just a bit of water in so it seals, but not so much that suck-back would pull it over the inner lip.

Answer (score 3):

I’m obviously years late to this conversation, but let me share my own experience.  After successfully fermenting several batches of sauerkraut in canning jars, I decided to purchase a fermentation crock.  I used the recommended 2% salt concentration and placed cabbage leaves over the kraut to catch floaties.  Next I positioned glass fermentation crock weights on top of the cabbage leaves.  I then pressed gently down until the brine covered the weights.  I added the lid and filled the moat.  I fermented @ 68-72 degrees F the first 10 days and then at 65-68 degrees F for the remaining 2 weeks.  During the second cooler stage, twice I noticed that the water level in the moat had receded quite a lot.  I had read that this is due to changes in barometric pressure and the solution is to NOT add more water.  Without actually lifting the lid (which will compromise your ferment) simply jiggle the lid a bit.  As soon as I did this, the water level on the outside of the moat returned to normal.  Obviously it’s possible that the moat water could evaporate a bit over three weeks or more of fermentation.  However, this would be gradual, not an overnight occurrence.  This has happened a few times and the issue was solved with simply jiggling the lid a little.  My sauerkraut turned out great with delicious and subtle depth in flavor and a crispy, fresh texture.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It might be late for the person originally asking the question, but still useful to those of us who are still fermentation novices

Answer (score -3):

I'm experiencing the same thing. Thank you for posting this!

Salt is very water soluable (salt is very negative, water is very positive), so salt will suck moisture out of the air, effectively drying the air. And dry air really absorbs moisture (for example cold air is very dry and drying). With fixed air inside, this would give us kind of a suction from the still soluable "thirsty" salt, through the sealed dry air to the water in the lid. Fascinating stuff!

Maybe there is too much salt in these ferments, so they are still "thirsty". But I'm not sure you can escape that with some ferments. In fermenting we use salt among other things to kill bad bacteria. Does salt still kill bad bacteria if it gets enough water that it becomes no longer soluable? I assume not because it probably dehydrates them. But worth researching.

So what can we do? The air inside these crocks is sealed, but with these types of lids the whole system is not sealed because you can just suck the water out of the lid. And you can't seal the whole system to prevent the water from getting sucked up or else you lose the one-way valve and air can't escape. Might as well just put a sealed lid on it.

A possibility is the lids with 2 separate water chambers. Maybe I will try that. Maybe the extra valve helps?

Another possibility is changing properties of the air in the crock. I got an idea to put a candle in a container before sealing it to burn up the oxygen. Maybe with no H20 in the air for the salt to absorb in the first place that would fix this kind of thing (as well as the huge benefit of totally inhibiting mold growth ;) But I'm not recommending this candle trick yet...still testing it. It would exhaust at least CO2 and trace amounts of CO. Seems relatively harmless to me. Maybe the type of wick matters. I wouldn't be surprised to discover if ancient people used candles all the time to help control their ferments and preserve food.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the brine is hygroscopic, which somehow produces a vacuum. That is not plausible. Sodium chloride is not strongly hygroscopic, a non-saturated brine is not hygroscopic at all, and absorbing moisture from the air would not create a vacuum.

Comment: Thanks for the word hygroscopic. I double checked. Pure sodium chloride is not, but rock salt and a lot of other not so refined salts are very hygroscopic. So certainly the salt could be drying the air inside. More questionable is, is dry air sucking up the lid moisture? The only thing i could find evaporating water at room temperature is boiling in a vacuum. I can't imagine the dry air would act as a vacuum in this way, but maybe it does somehow significantly reduce the surface tension inside. I mean something is pulling the water out of the lid into these ferments.

Comment: You’re drawing on a number of concepts which may not work like you think they work. Surface tension, for instance, has nothing to do with evaporation or pressure. And, again, a non-saturated brine is *not hygroscopic*, no matter what sort of salt you’ve got in there. What’s likely happening has already been explained by the other answer.